# How to prevent a field from being "removed" from the model once you turn it into a property in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I have a field that is a property, because it's the average of all reviews:

```
ratings = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
@property
def ratings(self):
    return self.reviews.aggregate(avg_score=Avg('score'))['avg_score']
```

The problem is that if I do this, then the field "disappears." In fact, if I run `makemigrations`, it deletes the field. The problem is that I use `django-filter`, and I want to have the option of filtering by ratings (show me all books that have between a 7 and a 10). If I make it into a property, I can't do it anymore because `django-filter` can't "detect" the field anymore.

Is there a way for me to still have property and the field at the same time? Can I maybe make a surrogate field that gets updated everytime ratings is changed and make it equal to that?

Comment: Give the property a different name than the field. Right now you "overwrite" the `ratings = ...` field with the property.

Comment: But if it's a different name how will it know what field it is linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can not make something both a field and a property at the same time. Furthermore I would advice *not* to use a field in the first place, since that will introduce *data duplication*: you save the data in an aggregated form somewhere else. It turns out that synchronizing data, even on the same database, is a much harder problem than it appears to be.

You can [**`annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset such that the database will calculate the aggregates automatically *per item* it retrieves. Such queryset looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    ratings=Avg('reviews__score')
)
```

If you need this value often, you can do that in the [**`Manager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) of the model:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            ratings=Avg('reviews__score')
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # … model without a ratings field
    objects = MyModelManager()
```